# Listener which notifies when job initialization is done with QUARTZ 2.2.x

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have implemented **quartz 2.2.0** for the scheduling job in my project.

Now i want to check some conditions before job starts.

So is there any listener method that can notify me when job initialized or when it is going to run for the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask if you use Spring or something else?

Comment: I am using spring..